# Ring Color on Hover using TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS for a project, and I'm stuck on a weird interraction.

The result I'm looking for is to have a ring outside a button when I hover it, but using the ring classes from Tailwind, I can't get the ring on hover, yet it work using focus.

Before filling a bug report, I thought maybe one you guys might see a mistake on my part before ?

I made the smallest possible codepen to reproduce my issue : https://codepen.io/Pymous/pen/bGBQKPO
The CodePen contains this simple code :

```
<button class="mt-4 ml-4 px-8 py-2 text-white bg-yellow-500 ring-offset-2 ring-transparent ring-2 focus:ring-red-500 hover:ring-red-500">
  Connexion
</button>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hover is not enabled by default according to tailwindcss's documenation.

> By default, only responsive, **focus-within** and **focus** variants
> are generated for ring width utilities.
>
> You can control which variants are generated for the ring width
> utilities by modifying the ringWidth property in the variants section
> of your tailwind.config.js file.
>
> For example, this config will also generate hover and active variants:
>
> ```
>   // tailwind.config.js
>      module.exports = {
>        variants: {
>          extend: {
>            // ...
>    
>           ringWidth: ['hover', 'active'],
>          }
>        }
>      }
> ```
>
> [https://tailwindcss.com](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/ring-width#variants)

Comment: Thanks ! I missed that in the docs, pretty straightforward ! I just need to get my custom tailwind to compile now then :D